# android set an alarm with only one repeat

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

at the moment i set an alarm in my android app like this:

```
scheduleNotification(getNotification("HELLO WORLD"), 5000, 1);

 private void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, int delay, int id) {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ShowNotification.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("NOTIFICATION_ID", id);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("NOTIFICATION", notification);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis() + delay,
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT));
}

private Notification getNotification(String content) {
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentText(content);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_appicon);
    return builder.getNotification();
}
```

is there an way, to set an alarm, which will be active one time and only one time 2 hours later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No set methods in AlarmManager does that. You should have your own counter to stop it after N times.

Answer (score 0):

You can set again the alarm when the first one fire. It is simple to do using the notificationIntent action.

The second time you set the alarm you shouldn't add a new alarm.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that alarm will be fired twice?
Once at specific time and other time 2 hours later?

You can us different id for the second alarm.

something like:

```
public final static int ID_DEFAULT = 1;
private final static int ID_REPEAT = 2;

...

switch (id) {
  case ID_DEFAULT:
    scheduleNotification(notification, DELAY_TWO_HOURS, ID_REPEAT);
  case ID_REPEAT:
    // Your code
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will invoke after 2 hours , try it

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, notificationId, myIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) activity.getSystemService(
                activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 7200000 , pendingIntent);
```